# Average stroke from a fill

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, inkscape, stroke

I would like to generate an average stroke from a given compound enclosed path, or fill, in Adobe Illustrator CC or Inkscape.

[image: Depiction of desired result of averaging a compound enclosed path]

Sorry I don't know the mathematical function name to achieve this. I've come upon a couple bizarre hacks involving Photoshop, but it stands to reason there is a simpler way to achieve this within a vector program. Unfortunately Illustrator's path averaging collapses my example into a single point, likely because it has both horizontal and vertical aspects.

Comment: Sounds like a mathematically highly non-trivial task to me. Even for a human it’s impossible to tell whether the result should be yours or one where there are two non-intersecting paths: one connecting the bottom two endpoints and one connecting the top two endpoints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Inkscape...

tl;dr **Interpolate paths**

As a generalized case, this is a very interesting question, for which I have a reasonable answer. However, your specific example is further complicated by the fact that your desired resulting "path" requires multiple disconnected, intersecting sub-paths (one for the horizontal line, and one for the vertical line). So, I'll be answering the more general (and simpler) case of one continuous, non-intersecting path, as summarized below:

[image: Summary]

Steps:

1. To set up the example, begin with a simple path having some substantial stroke width.

[image]

2. Choose "Path" > "Stroke to Path"

[image]

3. Mess with the nodes to create a more interesting example.

[image]

4. Remove fill, and set a thin stroke.

[image]

5. Delete the two endpoint segments. Then choose "Path" > "Break Apart"

[image]

6. *Important:* Select one of the resulting objects (either one) and choose **"Path" > "Reverse"**.
7. Select the two objects and choose "Extensions" > "Generate from path" > "Interpolate". (Make sure settings on the Interpolate extension are set as follows.

[image]

8. Delete the two original paths, leaving only the interpolated path. It will be a group. You can choose "Object" > "Ungroup" to remove the group container and just have a plain old path.

[image]

9. Style with thickness to taste. From here, you could simplify or tweak as desired.

[image]

Comment: Upon testing this method, I see what Sean meant by my example not being ideal. The lack of endpoints creates a problem which results in a non-meaningful interpolation. I went back and live-traced the original sketches in Adobe Illustrator in stead and saw there were some options for line art, which does a decent job if I tweak it and does create strokes. I have few enough samples that I can just draw in what I need, so I may just drop an automated solution and hope it doesn't come up again.