# Tracing a raster image to simple paths with stroke but no fill

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg

I have googled extensively on this, and am running around in circles.

I have a program that outputs isobars - lines of equal pressure. I can output these as .ps, .png, .jpg, and .kmz files.

What I need (ideally!) is to get them into omnigraffle, as vectors. This can be achieved if I can get them into pdf format - omnigraffle will happily read that.

I have spent some money on various apps, and have Inkscape, but I am struggling.
- If I use a 'convert to paths' tool, it invariable creates shapes rather than lines, to account for what it perceives as different thicknesses. I just want lines.
- If I try and 'trace' using the freehand tool on the omnigraffle app, it produces raster lines - not what I want
- If I try and 'trace' using the bezier tool on the omnigraffle app or program, it produces something nothing like the image I'm tracing, and is impossible to tweak (I have multiple images)

I've attached an example of the image I'm trying to recreate. I have Inkscape, Omnigraffle, and various apps. Not averse to spending a few pounds on different software, but ideally do not want to shell out for a full copy of illustrator!

Any pointers gratefully received. 
[image: example image of isobars]

Comment: It's really too bad you don't have access to Illustrator. This can be achieved very easily in it. If this isn't a long term project, you might be able to get away with the free trial version?

Comment: Hi @GoofyMonkey, thanks for that :-). Could you let me know how I'd do it in illustrator, and I'll see if I can get a trial version?

Comment: Sure! See below. Hopefully it makes sense. Play with the settings, it's hard to predict exactly what settings will give you a good result.

Comment: See http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60107/convert-a-line-drawing-from-raster-to-vector-lines for vectorizing to lines rather than shapes.

Comment: Oh. My god. Why everyone starts only recomending Ilustrator? James, What program are you using to generate the file? Because there is a chance the .KMZ file format or .PS file are vector information. Actually .PS could be the granddaddy of PDF.

Comment: Also, do they only output black and white lines? or can you have some color gradient shapes?

Comment: And tracing can be done in Inkscape too. https://inkscape.org/es/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html Ill post that as part of an answer but Let us explore the PS file first.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael. I have Inkscape, and I've tried the tracing tool, but it doesn't seem to get me where I want to be - largely the lack of 'centreline tracing' it seems. I've also had a look at VectorMagic, and that seems to be shapes rather than paths. I may be using the settings wrong. The .ps file - I have nothing here that will open that :-(

Comment: Can you link to a sample .kmz-File?

Comment: I would merely redraw it by hand, using the image as a manual tracing guide. Better, cleaner, paths that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a line drawing from raster to vector \*\*LINES\*\*](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60107/convert-a-line-drawing-from-raster-to-vector-lines)

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will help you out! These are the steps I took to create a line only (no fills) version of your graphic.

1. Open your png or jpg file in Illustrator. (Alternatively you can create a new document and drag or place the png/jpg in)
2. With the graphic selected, choose Image Trace > Make from the Object menu.

[image]

3. Open the the Image trace Panel (Window > Image Trace).
4. Choose Line Art from the Presets drop down.

[image]

5. Adjust the Threshold to something pretty high (I used 249.
6. Twirl down the advanced options and make sure that the Stokes toggle is picked and the fills is not.

[image]

7. You may want to play with the Advanced sliders a bit too, to get yourself a better result. This is always a play around and see what happens part for me.
8. Click the Ignore White Toggle
9. Once you are happy with what you are seeing on screen, choose Object > Image Trace > Expand
10. You should have a nice line art image to use. You may need to tweak some of the previous settings if you want things like the type to come out clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that Illustrator is completely overkill for tracing images into vectors. Use **Inkscape** and use the **Trace Bitmap** tool.

Select the image in Inkscape. Then use *Path* menu and select *Trace Bitmap*.

Click on the **OK** button to try the default settings.

It creates a vector object (a path) on top of the original, so you have to deselect everything, then click the black part of one of the lines (because it will be the vectored path set) and drag it off to the side. Then you can delete the original if you want. But you might feel safer keeping things on separate layers.

Keep all your work in **.SVG** for future edits, and export it in whatever format you need to open in Omni-whatsit.

Comment: It turns out inkscape's Trace Bitmap tool creates paths using fill, not a stroke like the OP requested.  If it can use stroke-only I have not found the option to do that.

Answer (score 0):

- beg, steal or borrow a copy of Adobe Illustrator (sorry for an ancient version but it still works and does not want regular payments)
- work some basic tutorials or get a friend to help
- paste or "Place" your bitmap image onto empty work in Illustrator
- select the bitmap
- choose Object > Live Trace > Tracing options
- put the preview on and try to find proper combination (see the screenshot). The settings are essential for different kind of images to get the wanted features well traced
- press Trace
- select and kill the unwanted parts (you should preclean the bitmap image in a photo editor to keep the tracing results manageable)
- insert the texts and other needed new data
- save your work

[image: maptrace]

Another option is to use online services. Here is a preview of VectorMagic's output. Probably very good result as a scalable version of your photo. Unfortunately the bad quality texts and the scale were not wiped off before sending it to Vector Magic. These should be inserted afterwards by hand in Illustrator or any Vector Graphics program.  NOTE: Commercial services -as usually - want some money.

[image: Vectormacic]

A third option: Try a dedicated program that is intended for those who scan technical drawings and want to have a DXF (=standard format in technical documents) . Running the trial reveals the usefulness. Do a web search "convert image to dxf" to find them. WinTopo is one example.It has free and paid versions. [WinTopo](http://wintopo.com/index.htm)

Comment: @James Davies new options added